# How to append the div element in jquery if don't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am adding the form my current list in a div box at the bottom of the table.
I am appending the div box when someone clicks on add button.

But when i click add button multiple times , then many div boxes are appended.

Is there any way that no matter how many times I click the button, only one instance gets append to div box.

This is my code

```
$var = $(this).parent().parent();
$var.append($('.jq_div')[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be having a boolean flag that you can toggle once your button is clicked. Additionally, there is actually a jQuery function that provides this exact functionality.

It's called `one()` -

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element.

So your code would look something like this -

```
$("#someTrigger").one('click', function(){
  $var = $(this).parent().parent();
  $var.append($('.jq_div')[0].outerHTML);
});
```

The boolean method is also very simple -

```
var wasClicked = false;

$("#someTrigger").on('click', function(){
  if (wasClicked == false){
    // append your form
    wasClicked = true;
  }
});
```

Reference -

- [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 4):

attach your listener using `.one()`.

```
$("button").one('click', function(){
  // Your code
});
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/one

This is under the assumption that you're using jQuery 1.7+

Comment: if i replace on with one , can it dynamically get attached to new dom elements

Comment: @user1721949 - yes. but you would know this if you read the documentation at the link provided ;-)

Comment: I tried this function  but its not working properly. First it append the div. next time it don't append the div but gets the user to href link on next page, rather than doing nothing

Comment: Sounds like your add *button* isn't a *button* at all. You'll have to just attach another handler using `.on()` that prevents the default action.